# Box-sizing with * selector is adding unwanted padding

Tags: css, css-selectors

I am using box-sizing and padding in my responsive design.

Effectively by using the following code:

```
.col * {
}
```

I am able to target everything within my section named 'col'. This is great, until I start adding elements within each other, then the class gets added again.

I have put together an example here http://jsfiddle.net/XS7KB/1/. You will see that the first line of the `<h1>` has the box-sizing added again because of the href. I would imagine it's the same if I add another span, list, hr ect. This could be problematic.

What im looking for is a way to apply this to the first set of tags and nothing in between. Perhaps a different selector would prevent this from happening.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What do you mean by "first set of tags"?

Comment: If I had, for example `<h1><a href=""></a>Heading</h1>` I only want the padding to be applied to the <h1> not the `<h1>` and the `<a>`. The JS Fiddle example works until I start adding links ect into the headings and paragraphs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If by "first set" you mean "first nesting level", use the child selector to limit it only to that set of elements:

```
.col > * {
}
```

This will only select the `h1` and `p` which are children of `.col`, and not anything inside them.

[Updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/BoltClock/XS7KB/2)